# Both A and B and C

Tags: grammar

Can you use "both" to refer to three parties? E.g., both A and B and C do something.

I found this example in this document here.

> Both you and your preparer(s) and/or translator(s) must complete the
> appropriate areas of Section 1, and then sign Section 1.

https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-9instr.pdf

Comment: The example doesn't say all 3 must sign, it says at least 2 must sign, so both is appropriate. Just as you might say "both the child and their parent or guardian".

Comment: You must be one signatory. One of your preparer(s) and/or translator(s) must be the other.

Comment: I read this differently.  I understand that *any* translators or preparers must sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use both with three parties.  The example given isn't very well written, as it is confusing.

It is about a situation in which you might have either a preparer, or a translator, or possibly both, possibly a team of preparers and translators. And so:

> both
>
> - you,  and
> - your preparation and translation team
>
> should sign.

(I read this differently from the commentators.  I understand this to mean every person involved in the preparation and translation of the document is required to sign to confirm that they have prepared or translated honestly.)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!

Comment: What if it was really referring to three parties? Then what should be used? [Both?]...... you and your company and your country should have concent. (For example)

Comment: You should not use both with three parties.  Either use nothing "A, B, and C should sign" or use a phrase like "All of A, B, and C should sign".

Comment: Got it, thanks.